# Testing fragment using FragmentScenario results in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

> I have tried to test my fragment using fragment scenario but I always get the below error

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun fab() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<HomeFragment>()
    }
}.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not
>   perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>       at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.runOnMainSync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:441)
>       at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:564)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.internalLaunch(FragmentScenario.java:300)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:282)
>       at com.example.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragmentTest.fab(HomeFragmentTest.kt:31)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
>       at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
>       at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2209)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1691)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1794)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1814)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:297)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:317)
>       at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:301)
>       at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:551)
>       at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2227)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)